# Find a text with multiple lines and selenium webdriver. Using driver.pageSource().contains

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find multiple lines of text using Selenium WebDriver. For example, I have this html:

```
<div class="record-label" data-name="age_child1_c">
    LBL_AGE_CHILD
</div>
```

If I code:

```
driver.pageSource().contains("LBL_AGE_CHILD")
```

Selenium is able to locate that line.

But I need to locate `>LBL_` when `>` and `LBL_` are in different lines. I tried it using \n:

```
driver.pageSource().contains(">\nLBL_")
```

but it didn't work. Does anyone know how I can locate that pattern being a string in different lines?

**EDITED after JeffC answer:**

My final goal is locate "LBL_" in a given page.
Because of that i thought:
driver.getPageSource().contains("LBL_); is the better way.
This line looks for "LBL_" on the code even if "LBL_" is not displayed at that moment, what is interesting for my reaching my goal.

The problem is if selenium looks for "LBL_" on the code, could find in the most cases, some attribute containing "LBL_", for example:
menu-item="LBL_CREATE_DASHBOARD_MENU"

This "LBL_" is never displayed on the page, because of that i don't want to locate it. When a "LBL_" is displayed on the page is always under pattern: ">LBL_" (However > and LBL_ could be in different lines, like this case)

Comment: OK. This makes more sense now. I see what you are trying to do... you want to find the string, "LBL_" no matter where it's found on the page, hidden or visible elements, etc. So when you find "LBL_", what do you want to do? Do you want to print the element that contains it or print the rest of the LBL_ ... string or ?

Comment: Make a Boolean variable, which value depends on whether LBL_ is present or not and use this variable in a Junit assertion to run a test.

Comment: Well that's a lot more simple than I thought... so why isn't `driver.pageSource().contains("LBL_AGE_CHILD")` good enough? Why are you trying to look for the ">"?

Comment: Because "LBL_AGE_CHILD" is just an example . I need locate the labels which begin with "LBL_" and appearing on the website too. That's the reason why i can't use ">", because the pattern is in the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Do over after new info...

If you really need to find ">(something)LBL_(something)" then I would look into Regex. Something like this should point you in the right direction.

```
String regex = ">\\s*(LBL_\\w+)\\s*<";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(pageSource);
matcher.find();
System.out.println("Count: " + matcher.groupCount());
for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, 

I don't know where is the pattern ">LBL_" on the code in a real case. So, i couldn't use that cssSelector because the pattern could even appear many times on the code under different unknown cssSelectors.

Comment: My final goal is locate "LBL_" in a given page.
Because of that i thought:
driver.getPageSource().contains("LBL_"); is the better way.
This line looks for "LBL_" on the code even if "LBL_" is not displayed at that moment, what is interesting for my reaching my goal.

The problem is if selenium looks for "LBL_" on the code, could find in the most cases, some attribute containing "LBL_", for example:
menu-item="LBL_CREATE_DASHBOARD_MENU"

This "LBL_" is never displayed on the page, because of that i don't want to locate it. When a "LBL_" is displayed on the page is always under pattern: ">LBL_"